# Calling a php script from javascript onclick

Tags: php, ajax

i want to execute a php script when i click on a button in html generated by javascript,i was trying with jquery ajax and i did this but nothing happens...any help pls?the php script is working so its not that,i guess i am missing something in this ajax call...

**Ajax call**

```
$(".formBtn").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: "script to call",
        type: "post",

        // callback handler that will be called on success
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
            // log a message to the console
            console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
            alert("Working!");
        },
        // callback handler that will be called on error
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            // log the error to the console
            console.log(
                "The following error occured: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        },
        // callback handler that will be called on completion
        // which means, either on success or error
        complete: function(){
            // enable the inputs
            $inputs.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

});
```

**PHP srcipt**

```
$api_key = 'apikey';
    $project_id = 'projectid';
    $phone_id = 'phoneid';    
    $to_number = 'number';
    $content = 'content';


    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 
        "urlblblbll");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$api_key}:");  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
        'content' => $content,
        'phone_id' => $phone_id,
        'to_number' => $to_number,

    )));        



    $json = curl_exec($curl);    
    if ($err = curl_error($curl)) { echo "$err\n"; }    
    curl_close($curl);    

    $res = json_decode($json, true);        

    var_dump($res); // do something with $res
    }
```

Comment: Is there any error in the console?

Comment: No , Return with a blank page

Comment: The return value of `curl_exec` is true/false. So i think issue is because of that.

Comment: Not true - he has added the `RETURN_TRANSFER` parameter, so the return should be the result of the request

Comment: Why are you `var_dump`ing res? You should probably be `echo`ing it so that the browser can read the return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $result = curl_exec($curl);   
 if($result)
 {
    $json['result'] = 'true';
 } 
 else
 {
    $json['result'] = 'false';
 }
if ($err = curl_error($curl)) { echo "$err\n"; }    
curl_close($curl);    

$res = json_decode($json, true);
```

Can you try this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to echo something on the php page, because ajax's data is based on the output from the php file.